# TOTALYTD with Categories doesn't correctly aggregate - Power BI / DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data set with the following format:

```
Category          Type         Date     Hours
A               Billable    1/1/2018    8
A               Billable    1/2/2018    10
A               Billable    1/3/2018    7
B               Billable    1/4/2018    8
B               Billable    1/5/2018    10
B               Billable    1/6/2018    7
Not assigned    Available   1/1/2018    8
Not assigned    Available   1/2/2018    8
Not assigned    Available   1/3/2018    8
Not assigned    Available   1/4/2018    8
Not assigned    Available   1/5/2018    8
Not assigned    Available   1/6/2018    8
```

I've got a cumulative calculation using `TOTALYTD`. The calculation is YTD utilization of a resource (i.e., Billable / Available). So, the formula is:

```
ytd_billable = TOTALYTD(Sum(Hours[Hours]),Hours[Date],Hours[Type]="Billable")
ytd_available = TOTALYTD(Sum(Hours[Hours]),Hours[Date],Hours[Type]="Available")
ytd_utilization = [ytd_billable] / [ytd_available]
```

Now, this works just fine when I plot this with date as the `x axis` and `ytd_utilization` as the values of the plot. However, when I add **Category** to the chart, I get infinity for each group rather than the value of `ytd_utilization` for each level of *Category*. How do I get the desired behavior? See graphs below for what I'm looking for (graphs are based different data, but same structure):

**YTD Utilization w/o Category - works**
[image]

**YTD Utilization w/ Category - doesn't work**
[image]

**YTD Utilization - what I'm looking for (had to alter my data to get this, but don't want to do this for solution)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ytd_billable` can be categorized (A, B, etc) while `ytd_available` cannot (Not assigned).

For example, for Category A, `ytd_billable` = 25, but there is no corresponding Category A Type Available data (i.e. `ytd_available` = 0), hence the infinity result because of division by 0.

It's easier to catch it in tabular form:

[image: division by zero]

---

Here I assume that the `Available` hours are independent of `Category`.

One way to the fix the problem is to remove the filter on category when calculating `ytd_available`, using the [ALL() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/all-function-dax):

```
ytd_available =
TOTALYTD(
    SUM(Hours[Hours]),
    Hours[Date],
    FILTER(ALL(Hours), Hours[Type]="Available")
)
```

Results:

[image: results]

Notice that for Category A, it only counts till March for `ytd_available`. Depending on the definition of `Available` hours, you may also need to change `Hours[Date]` to `ALL(Hours[Date])` to get the results you want.

Comment: Hi @ryan-erwin does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to positively close the question.